# Counting measure and integration

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let the measures spaces $([0,1], B_\mathbb{R}, l)$ and $([0,1], B_\mathbb{R}, \nu)$, where $\nu$ is counting measure. Define $D=\{(x,x): x \in [0,1]\} $

Calculate $\int_{[0,1]} \int_{[0,1]} 1_D (x,y) d_\nu(y) d_l(x)$ and $\int_{[0,1]} \int_{[0,1]} 1_D (x,y) d_l(x) d_\nu(y)$

I don't know if I need to use Tonelli's theorem or Fubini's and how to start, and how to integrate in $[0,1]$, any help will be grateful!

Comment: Compute the inner integrals first: for instance $$\int_{[0,1]}\mathbf1_D(x,y)\,\mathrm d\nu(y)=\nu\!\left(\Bigl\{y\in[0,1]:y=x\Bigr\}\right)\!.$$

Comment: I think this exercise is to show you why $\sigma$-additivity of measures is required for Fubini's theorems to apply.

Comment: Thanks for your help!!, the first integral is equal to 0, and the second integral is equal to 1, and its contradicts the Tonelli/Fubini's theorem. Right?

Comment: Yes (the assumptions of those theorems are not fulfilled).